# Make my IP publicly accesible

Tags: networking, ip

I have this ip 19.46.1.34 ,how to make it publicly accessible around the world?

Comment: are you sure that's the IP you have? 1) It is a publicly routable IP already and 2) it is owned by the Ford motor company.

Comment: yes , I can access that within our local network.

Comment: What kind of service from your computer do you want to make publicly accessible? Why do you think it isn't publicly accessible right now?

Comment: @MadMike--> Im currently using Google Docs Viewer in my website. The Google Doc Viewer is not loading anything. I suspect the Google Docs Viewer cant access publicly my computer to get my pdf bitstream.

Answer (score 1):

You need to talk to whoever gave that IP to you. Most likely they would need to reconfigure a router/firewall or 2 to make it happen. Also most likely this would be against the company policy and they would not do that.

If you created that IP yourself then you can't make it publicly accessible.

You will need to tell us more about your network topology if you want us to have a chance to help you.